# how to fix webpack build error , bezierEasingMixin() after install antdesign in my project?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

here is my webpack config which shows i've added rules for less files, also as you can see in package.json, I have installed all less less-loader css-loader and whatever is needed for adding styles.
but I constantly get these errors when building project
what's wrong with my codes?
thanks a lot in advance

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const fs  = require('fs')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const lessToJs = require('less-vars-to-js')

const themeVariables = lessToJs(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './ant-theme-vars.less'), 'utf8'))
// lessToJs does not support @icon-url: "some-string", so we are manually adding it to the produced themeVariables js object here
themeVariables["@icon-url"] = "'http://localhost:8080/fonts/iconfont'";

const ebMode = process.env.eb_mode
const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'


const version = new Date().getTime().toString()
const createConfig = (label, entry, target) => ({
  entry,
  output: {
    filename: `app.js?v=${version}`,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, `dist/${label}`),
  },
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv(),
    // new CopyWebpackPlugin({
    //   patterns: [
    //     { from: './assets', to: './' }
    //   ],
    // }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: `${label} admin panel`,
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, `public/${label}/index.html`),
      filename: path.resolve(__dirname, `dist/${label}/index.html`),
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx', '.css', '.less'] },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
            {loader: 'style-loader'},
            {loader: 'css-loader'},
            {loader: 'less-loader',
                options: {
                  lessOptions: {
                    strictMath: true,
                  },
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      test: /\.css$/
      }
    ],
  },
})

module.exports = createConfig
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ant-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config ./main.webpack.config.js --mode production",
    "watch": "webpack --config ./main.webpack.config.js --mode=development --watch",
    "live": "serve -s -l 80 dist/main"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^4.12.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jss": "^10.5.1",
    "jss-preset-default": "^10.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-jss": "^10.5.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.17",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.17",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.0",
    "less": "^4.1.1",
    "less-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "less-vars-to-js": "^1.3.0",
    "serve": "^11.3.2",
    "string-replace-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.23.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

.babalrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "import",
      {
        "libraryName": "antd",
        "style": true
      }
    ]
  ],
}
```

and finaly here is the error details

[image]

Comment: any update maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `javascriptEnabled: true` in `webpack.confg.js` in the options section:

```
use: [
  "style-loader", 
  "css-loader", 
  "postcss-loader", 
  {
    loader: "less-loader",
    options: {
      lessOptions: {
        // This line
        javascriptEnabled: true,
      },
    },
  },
],
```